Douban reviews crawling error: can't crawl comments
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
chrome_ver = chromedriver_autoinstaller.get_chrome_version().split('.')[0]
print(chrome_ver)

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time

customService = Service()
customOption = Options()
crawler = webdriver.Chrome(service=customService, options=customOption)
crawler.get('https://www.douban.com')

# Execute login before running cells.
# Click on 'Movies' on Douban.
crawler.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="anony-nav"]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()

# Handling new window.
crawler.switch_to.window(crawler.window_handles[-1])
# Click on 'TV Shows'.
crawler.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="db-nav-movie"]/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a').click()

time.sleep(3)

# Click on 'Region' (If the real-time location changes and selects a different menu, modify the xpath).
crawler.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div').click()

time.sleep(3)

# Click on 'Korea' (If the real-time location changes and selects a different menu, modify the xpath).
crawler.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[5]').click()

time.sleep(3)

# Click on the drama title (If the real-time location changes and selects a different title, modify the xpath).
# Please specify the drama title in Chinese! Drama Title: (黑暗荣耀)
crawler.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a/div').click()

# Handling new window.
crawler.switch_to.window(crawler.window_handles[-1])
# Click on 'More Reviews'.
# //*[@id="reviews-wrapper"]/p/a
crawler.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="hot-comments"]/a').click()

nicknames = []
likes = []
dates = []
comments = []

for i in range(1, 4, 1):
    crawler.get('https://movie.douban.com/subject/35314632/reviews?start={}'.format(i))

    while True:
        bh = crawler.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")  # Initial browser height.
        print(bh)
        time.sleep(4)
        crawler.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")  # Scroll down.    
        time.sleep(4)
        ah = crawler.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if ah == bh:
            break
        bh = ah
    infos = crawler.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".main-hd")
    infos1 = crawler.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".main-bd")

# The for loops are divided into two because the HTML structure of Douban assigns an id first
# and divides it into 'main-hd' and 'main-bd' classes under each id.
# 'main-hd' contains img, name, like, and time, while 'main-bd' contains review-short.
# So by separating 'class_name, main-hd' and 'class_name, main-bd',
# and saving them into two variables (infos, infos1),
# the for loops ensure only the nickname, like, date, and comment for the first review of each page are extracted,
# thus avoiding the influence of the first assigned id.

    for info in infos:
        try:
            nickname = info.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'CSS_SELECTOR of name').text
            nicknames.append(nickname)
            like = info.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'TAG_NAME where like is located').get_attribute('corresponding_attribute')
            likes.append(like)
            date = info.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'CSS_SELECTOR of date').text
            dates.append(date)

        except:
            print('Exception')

    for info1 in infos1:
        try:
            comment = info1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'CSS_SELECTOR of comment').text
            comments.append(comment)

        except:
            print('Exception')

crawler.close()

df = pd.DataFrame({'nickname': nicknames, 'like': likes, 'date': dates, 'comment': comments})
print(df)
# Filename should be written according to the manual, refer to the example below.
# CSV delimiter is set as (,), and encoding is specified as utf-8-sig.
df.to_csv('./豆瓣_黑暗荣耀.csv', sep=",", encoding="utf-8-sig")

# Note: If you want to save it as an Excel file.
df.to_excel('豆瓣_黑暗荣耀.xlsx', header=['nickname', 'like', 'date', 'comment'], index=None)

I want to crawl comments for reviews of the drama at the Douban website. The code to automatically access to that review site seems fine, but the problem is that when I start crawling the comments - they all print 'exception'. From the fact that empty lists are produced when extracting, it appears that crawling isn't happening. It seems that fixing lines 86-107 should resolve the issue.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
